# Why can "that is" be omitted in this relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, ellipsis

In the sentence below, **"That is"** before adjective **permanent** has been dropped.

> There is a saying, which says, “The only thing permanent in life is
>   change”

According to this [link](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/adjective_clauses03.html), The relative pronoun and BE are not "dropped" when BE is followed by an adjective.

So my question is that how **"that is"** has been dropped in **"The only thing permanent..."** ?

Comment: Here's one analysis: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/28567

Comment: what i understand from the link is that **relative pronoun and BE are not dropped** in the sentences like "I am reading a book that is exciting", because there is only one adjective left after deletion but **relative pronoun and BE can be dropped** in the sentences like "Bill is a man who is happy to see you" because **happy to see you** is left after deletion not just the adjective. am i right?

Comment: Read professor Lawler's explanation carefully: "when there is **only one adjective left after deletion**. The adjective has to be moved in front of the noun". If your sentence read: *In life, change is the only thing that is permanent* saying: *In live, change is the only thing permanent* would be odd. But in your example the adjective isn't the only thing left after deletion.

Comment: @Lucky: Are you parsing "thing permanent in life" as "thing {permanent {in life}}"? With "in life" modifying "permanent"?

Comment: @ruach: I would say so. "in life" clarifies where (or for how long) the thing ("change") is permanent. But this means that in the offered phrasing, "permanent" is not being treated as an absolute.  Maybe that's why the way the idiom is usually phrased is "the only thing _constant_... ( I was going to say _certain_, but that's in a different idiom: " The only things certain in life are death and taxes.")

Comment: When you've lost everything, the only thing left is laughter.

Comment: Actually the "rule" of the link refers only to a single adjective. And normally an adjective is not placed after a noun but before. (Of  course there are some cases where an adjective is placed after a noun.) But your rule does not refer to longer adjective groups.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives answer the question *which* or *what kind* for a noun.

But you can also answer these questions with in a wordier form with a *{noun} that is {property}* pattern, since *to be* is a copular verb that completes with a subject complement, and adjectives work as subject complements.

> I looked at the car that is red.
>
> I looked at the red car.

No difference in meaning, it's just a stylistic choice of whether you want to use more or less words.

Typically you want to use the adjective unless the adjective is something like a complex adjective phrase or clause, or you want to use more words to ensure a listener/reader understands better.

English likes to place adjectives before the noun, but it's possible to for them to be *postpositive* or happen after the noun.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) on these details when this usually happens.  In this case, I believe the following applies:

> One common situation in which adjectives appear postpositively in English is when they qualify compound indefinite pronouns: something, anyone, nobody, somewhere, etc. Examples: We need someone strong; Going anywhere nice?; Nothing important happened.

Even though *only thing* is not a pronoun, it's working enough like one possibly for the above to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is permanent in life is change.

The defining relative clause "That is permanent in life" in the sentence has a subject-pattern adjective clause "that is permanent".  According to grammar, such a clause can be reduced to an adjective phrase by removing the relative pronoun + be. So it's correct to say:

The only thing permanent in life is change.